# Retrieve hash fragment from url with Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

Given this url structure (over which I have no control), how can I retrieve the hash fragment using Angular2?

`http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

My router does route to the correct component, but everything after `oauth` get scrapped and I can't find the hash fragment in request.params or location.path. Doomed??

Router config:

```
@RouteConfig([
{path: '/welcome', name: 'Welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
{path: '/landing/oauth', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent}  // this one
```

])

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For those still looking :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  myfunction(){
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
        console.log("My hash fragment is here => ", fragment)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to worry about [unsubscribing from ActivatedRoute observables](https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse):
> The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.

Answer (score 20):

To expand on the current answers, I wanted to address an easy way to parse the query params in the hash (specifically for a federated response) since the `ActivatedRoute` doesn't seem to handle that natively.

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
  const response = _.fromPairs(Array.from(new URLSearchParams(fragment)));
  response.access_token;
  response.id_token;
  response.expires_in;
  response.token_type;
});
```

First create a new [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object with the fragment to query for its values:

```
new URLSearchParams(fragment).get('access_token');
```

For most cases this is probably all that is needed, but if converting this to an object is desired, `Array.from` converts `URLSearchParams` into an array of arrays that looks like: `[['key', 'value'], ...]`.  Then lodash's `_.fromPairs` converts this to an object.

Comment: The next step after finding `this.route.fragment` to get the fragment is to search how to parse its queries. Thanks for adding `URLSearchParams` snippet!

Comment: Great Answer! I was able to grab the fragment but I was left with multiple params to parse through. Your answer saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 15):

you can also use [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) with no need to subscribe for all changes on it.

```
@Component({templateUrl:'./my-component.html'})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const fragment: string = route.snapshot.fragment;
  }
}
```

Comment: @MochamadArifin I think that what you need.

Comment: Awesome, this is the most simplest solution thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I've taken the comment from nwayve and implemented it using RxJS pipes like this:

```
this.route.fragment
  .pipe(
    map(fragment => new URLSearchParams(fragment)),
    map(params => ({
      access_token: params.get('access_token'),
      id_token: params.get('id_token'),
      error: params.get('error'),
    }))
  )
  .subscribe(res => console.log('', res));
```

Comment: Note that if you have OAuth2.0 access tokens they can include `+` which will become a whitespace character in your access token.

Comment: @DanielB if you have an access token  "4XVjonKI1k+" with a plus sign, and  the code above is getting the access token from a URL encoded string then the access token will have a space like ""4XVjonKI1k " instead of the +? To fix this we need to add decodeURIComponent(params.get("access_token"))? Did I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using *ActivatedRoute* class in your constructor, try this:

```
let params = this.route.snapshot.fragment;

const data = JSON.parse(
    '{"' +
        decodeURI(params)
            .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
            .replace(/&/g, '","')
            .replace(/=/g, '":"') +
        '"}'
);

console.log(data); // { json: "with your properties"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem by requesting OAuth server with `response_type`=`token`, and who redirects to `%REDIRECT_URI%#access_token=:access_token&token_type=:token_type&expires_in=:expires_in`.

The problem is, by default, the direct access to sub-url is not routed: in your case, `%BASE_URL%/landing/oauth` will not be redirect to `LandingComponent` component.

I fixed it with this configuration:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' }) // this line
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

An option for parsing the fragment data with plain javascript is

```
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(value => {
  let fragments = value.split('&')
  let fragment = {}
  fragments.forEach(x => {
    let y = x.split('=')
    fragment[y[0]] = y[1]
  })
})
```

The information will be in the form of an object which can be easily accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but the snapshot was an empty string. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286916/569302

Here's what worked for me:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe({ 
        next: value => {
        if (value === null) {
          throw new Error('not implemented');
        }
        const access_token = new URLSearchParams(value).get('access_token')
        console.log({access_token})
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the url fragment at any time using the following code - which makes use of the `Router` service:

```
const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
console.log(urlTree.fragment); //access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only 'angular only' solution that worked for me (

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(
    private router: Router,) {}
...

ngOnInit() { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log("route change url", event.url)
      }
    });
}
```

from a URL of **http://localhost:8100/#/activity** prints **/activity**